# Like search not returning records when where method does

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, sql-like

I have the following query

```
Suburb.where("name ILIKE ?", '%#{"Camp Hill"}%').to_a
```

which returns an empty array. However if I run

```
Suburb.where(name: "Camp Hill").to_a
```

I'm returned a record. I have no idea why this doesn't work. Am I missing a nuance feature of ILIKE in postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Suburb.where("name ILIKE ?", '%Camp Hill%')
```

If you want to use a variable in place of `Camp Hill` then you need to make sure you wrap the string with double quotes to get the interpolation to work and not single quotes, like follows (Note the enclosing double quotes where you've used single quote):

```
Suburb.where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{my_var}%")
```